# how do i stop reqest.finish() (twisted .web server)from closing the http connection

Tags: twisted, twisted.web

I have written a chat server which writes a message line on the browser of one client to other client. The problem is that if i use request.finish() the output is shown but the connection is closed .if i dont use request.finish () the browser or program buffers the output and displaying output only after 20 or so request have been send.however the connection remains open.

Answer (score 0):

I think best approach is reconnecting client just after receiving a message and closing connection.